# Earliest cooperative board game

Tags: history, cooperation, ancient-board-games

Which was the first [cooperative board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_board_game)?

For the purpose of this question, we can define "cooperative" as "there is more than one player, and at the end of the game, they either all win or all lose".

My unsuccessful attempts to answer the question:

- At the time when I am writing this, the history section on Wikipedia mentions an 'alternative ruleset' for *The Landlord's game* (1903) as an early example (without claiming it is the first); I could not easily google this ruleset to confirm that it fits the criterion.
- [Some sources](https://www.belloflostsouls.net/2018/08/retro-the-very-first-cooperative-board-game.html) cite *Community* (1972), but that seems quite late, given the other games mentioned on Wikipedia.
- Boardgamegeek has a [cooperative game](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2023/cooperative-game) category, but many of the listed games are clearly not cooperative with this definition, as their descriptions mention winning and losing teams. And there are various pages of games without a publication date in the list.

Comment: Probably indeterminate, as it will depend on the definition of game and where you draw the line between game and puzzle. The oldest coop game on BGG is such a puzzle: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/39814/mosaic-designer

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson But is Mosaic Designer really cooperative? From its description on BGG it seems the players have conflicting goals: "Players [...] attempt to [...] while the other players attempt to do the same or prevent this from happening". This is precisely one of the examples I mentioned in my last bullet points.

Comment: Yes, in the version in which the players would all cooperate to reproduce the pattern.

Comment: The question has been asked at BGG too: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/803965/please-tell-me-about-history-cooperative-board-gam

Comment: This is probably obvious, but does your game require more than one player? Otherwise any singleplayer game would qualify.

Comment: @Erik Fair point, I'll add it to the definition explicilty.

Comment: The first known jigsaw puzzle was made in the 1760s by John Spilsbury.  His design used a world map as the pattern and was intended as an educational tool.  That's likely a lower temporal bound for first cooperative board game.

Comment: @Zags That goes back to the definition of a game, but if "jigsaw puzzle" meets whatever definition the OP intends, that would make 1760s an upper temporal bound on the earliest, not a lower temporal bound.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not sure it is THE earliest, The Landlord's Game/Prosperty, the origin for what we now call monopoly, had two sets of rules. The first set of rules, The Landlord's Game, formed the basis for Monopoly, was competitive and was won by the first player to reach $2000 in cash. The second set of rules, Prosperity, was cooperative and was won by all players when all players had at least $7000. (This may be a typo in the rules since it also says double their starting capital, and each player started with $350, and the game had just over $8,000 included)

[The rules for both can be found here](https://landlordsgame.info/games/lgp-1932/lgp-1932_rules.pdf)